# How to specify FK names when using @JoinTable mapping?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have the following mapping:

```
//...
@Table(name="A")
public class A{
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")})
    public Set<B> getBs() {
            return this.meals;
        }
    //...
}

//...
@Table(name="B")
public class B{
  private int id;
  private String description;
  //...
}
```

How can specify the names of the foreign keys in table "A_B"? (FK_A_ID and FK_B_ID)

Thanks in advance,
Neuquino

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [@ForeignKey](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ForeignKey.html) to specify the name of the foreign key constraint in the join table .

For example:

```
@ForeignKey(name="FK_A_ID" , inverseName="FK_B_ID")
@JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")})
public Set<B> getBs() {
      return this.meals;
}
```

Then Table `A_B` has the following structure:

- A column called `A_ID` which has the foreign key constraint to the primary key of Table `A` .The name of this foreign key is `FK_A_ID`
- A column called `B_ID` which has the foreign key constraint to the primary key of Table `B`.The name of this foreign key is `FK_B_ID`

Comment: I want to change the name of the constraint, not the name of the column. For simple attributes I use @ForeignKey, but for a JoinTable I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @KenChan Do you have any idea how to do that in Hibernate 4.3, without deprecated org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey?

Comment: Turns out that's a bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8862 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103795/schema-generation-with-eclipselink-and-hibernate-jpa2-1-foreignkey-ignored)